# Creating a model for two jsonarray

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

```
demoAlerts({
    itemstatus: [
        {
            item: "1",
            name: "apple",
            type: "fruit"
        },
        {
            item: "2",
            name: "pine",
            type: "fruit"
        }
    ],
    deliverystatus: [
        {
            name: "james",
            status: "yes"
        },
        {
            name: "thomas",
            status: "no"
        },

    ]
});
```

I have two array (itemstatus and deliverystatus), I need to create the model for this store. what I tried is

**ParentModel:**

```
Ext.define('test.model.ParentModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    requires:['test.model.ItemModel','test.model.DeliveryModel'],
autoLoad: true,
    config : {
    fields : [ 'itemstatus', {
        name : 'demostatuslist',
        model : 'demoAlerts.model.ItemModel',
        mapping : 'itemstatus'
    },
     'portalstatus', {
            name : 'deliverystatus',
            model : 'test.model.DeliveryModel',
            mapping : ' deliverystatus'
        }]
    }

});
```

**ItemModel**

```
Ext.define('demoAlerts.model.ItemModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        fields: [
            { name: 'item', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'type', type: 'string' }

        ]
    }
});
```

**DeliveryModel**

```
Ext.define('demoAlerts.model.DeliveryModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'status', type: 'string' },


        ]
    }
});
```

Whether i properly configured the model. I am receiving the store as empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Associations :) http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.data.association.Association

In this case I would have a Model with 2 hasMany associations like this:

```
Ext.define('demoAlerts.model.ContainerModel', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    requires : [
        'demoAlerts.model.DeliveryModel',
        'demoAlerts.model.ItemModel'
    ],
    config : {
        associations: [
            {
                type           : 'hasMany',
                model          : 'demoAlerts.model.DeliveryModel',
                associationKey : 'deliveryStatus',
                name           : 'deliveryStatus',
                autoLoad       : true // this is very important
            },
            {
                type           : 'hasMany',
                model          : 'demoAlerts.model.ItemModel',
                associationKey : 'itemStatus',
                name           : 'itemStatus',
                autoLoad       : true // this is very important
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Then use a store SomeStore binded to ContainerModel.

**IMPORTANT Each record in SomeStore will have deliveryStatusStore and itemStatusStore AUTOGENERATED.**

Read about associations.

Comment: thanks man its working. Now i got clear idea about association. :)

Answer (score 0):

Neither http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Field
nor http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.field.Field

knows a valid config option "model" for a field.

- As far as I know, there is no such thing as a "Parent Model" available in ExtJS or Sencha Touch.
- As far as I know, there is no possibility to have two stores in one.

You can load two (or more) stores using only one call to the server like in my following example:

```
firststore.on('load',function() {
    secondstore.loadRawData(firststore.getProxy().getReader().rawData);
});
firststore.load()
```

Where you would give `firststore` the server `url` and the `root` of the data that goes into the first store, and `secondstore` will have the `root` of the data that goes into the second store.

Please be aware that the second store won't be filled if zero records go into the first store, and choose your stores appropriately.

If any of your stores can be the only empty store, perhaps you will have to get the rawdata via `Ext.data.Request` and load it into all stores afterwards.